# Python PGU Library - how do I install it?

Tags: python, user-interface, installation, pygame, pgu

I am developing a game in Python with `pygame` on Windows 8, and I wanted to add some buttons and stuff.  I found a library called [`PGU`](http://code.google.com/p/pgu/), but I don't really know how to install it.

If somebody can help me adding `PGU` to my `pygame`, it would be great.

Comment: Have you checked out the documentation included in the `pgu` package?

Comment: Yes, but still I can't figure it out. Every time I try to import pgu in the python idle it shows an error, so I want to know how to integrate it to python as we normally do, like with pygame...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer. When you download PGU and unzip it, inside the folder there are other two folders named "pgu" and "data". Copy them into your project's/program's root folder and you're done!

For more information: https://code.google.com/p/pgu/source/browse/trunk/INSTALL.txt?r=21

Comment: You should probably have explained your problem better. By reading your original post, there are no hints at what your problem is what so ever.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to install PGU is by using **`pip`**.

Once you have downloaded the .zip file from [here](https://code.google.com/p/pgu/downloads/list), you can proceed as follows:

```
pip install "path/to/file/pgu-0.18.zip
```

For more info about pip, read the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29).