# Intstall PGU Library in Python 3.6 (Windows 8) Error

Tags: python, windows-8, installation, pgu

I'm trying to install the PGU Library in Windows 8 from the Power Shell in different ways and searched throught this web page and others unsuccessfully. I have already tried the answers in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20983508/python-pgu-library-how-do-i-install-it) too.
This is what is shown in the PowerShell:

```
PS C:\Users\Núria> pip install pgu-0.18.zip
Requirement 'pgu-0.18.zip' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
Processing c:\users\núria\pgu-0.18.zip
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\núria\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in mai
n
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\núria\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 324, i
n run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "c:\users\núria\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in pre
pare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "c:\users\núria\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 620, in _pr
epare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "c:\users\núria\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 809, in unpack
_url
    unpack_file_url(link, location, download_dir, hashes=hashes)
  File "c:\users\núria\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 715, in unpack
_file_url
    unpack_file(from_path, location, content_type, link)
  File "c:\users\núria\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 599, in
unpack_file
    flatten=not filename.endswith('.whl')
  File "c:\users\núria\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 482, in
unzip_file
    zipfp = open(filename, 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Núria\\pgu-0.18.zip'
PS C:\Users\Núria> pip install pgu-0.18
Collecting pgu-0.18
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pgu-0.18 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pgu-0.18
PS C:\Users\Núria> cd Downloads/PYTHON3
PS C:\Users\Núria\Downloads\PYTHON3> pip install pgu-0.18
Collecting pgu-0.18
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pgu-0.18 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pgu-0.18
PS C:\Users\Núria\Downloads\PYTHON3> pip install pgu-0.18.zip
Processing c:\users\núria\downloads\python3\pgu-0.18.zip
Installing collected packages: pgu
  Running setup.py install for pgu ... error
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\núria\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in
console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfa in position 43: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\núria\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in mai
n
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\núria\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, i
n run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\users\núria\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in ins
tall
    **kwargs
  File "c:\users\núria\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in
 install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\users\núria\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in
call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\users\núria\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in
console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfa in position 43: invalid start byte
```

I don't understand where this error is coming from and how to solve it. Any help is welcome!

Comment: Can you please share the files that in the pgu-0.18.zip ?

Comment: I downloaded the latest version from here: [https://code.google.com/archive/p/pgu/downloads]

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the setup.py file:

```
str = unicode(str, errors='ignore')
```

Also, if there is a `requirements.txt` file in the folder that you are trying to install the module, please do this before all:

```
pip install requirements.txt
```

Comment: I tried adding `str = unicode(str, errors='ignore')` as you suggested in the setup file, but it is still failing since _unicode_ is not defined:
`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\NRIA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-umjxonff-build\`
In addition, my file does not have a requirements.txt file